# Restart systemd with different options without rebooting?

Tags: systemd, docker, cgroups

Is it possible to restart `systemd` and add/remove/override any options it gets from the kernel boot command-line (i.e. `/proc/cmdline`)?

I've run into the [bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=843509) with systemd 232 & docker on newish kernels where docker can't run any containers, with error messages like this:

```
# docker start containername
Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = 2 desc = "oci runtime error: could not synchronise with container process: no subsystem for mount"
Error: failed to start containers: containername
```

I know I can get it working by editing my grub config to make the machine reboot with `systemd.legacy_systemd_cgroup_controller=1` (i've done that on another machine, and it works), but I really don't want to reboot right now.  It would take hours to get my "context" back to where I need it to be.

So, is there any systemd config file i can edit, or argument I can pass to `systemctl daemon-reexec` or `daemon-reload`, or anything else I can do to get systemd to restart with that setting without rebooting?

Comment: anonymous downvoter - if this is such a bad question then explain why.  or if it's a dumb question with an obvious answer, then post it and get at least one upvote.  so far, there are no answers, so i'm guessing that if there is any answer, it's non-obvious.